# Is there any way to store Autotext (GlossaryDocument) in docx instead of dotx

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I need make word file with some autotext (generated from database)
Now I programmatically generate word document (docx) and template for it (dotx). Dotx contains list of autotext (in GlossaryDocument) and in docx file I paste relation on it:

```
documentSettingPart1.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate", new Uri($"file:./{Path.GetFileName(dotxTemplate)}", UriKind.Relative) , relationId);
```

So If user save both files in the same directory and open docx, he can use autotext perfectly. But I looking for a way to realize it in one docx file because it's inconvenient for users to have two files and make sure they are in the same directory. 
I tried add GlossaryDocumentPart in docx or change document type (ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)) but after that I see GlossaryDocument in open xml sdk, but when I open docx-file in Word there are not any autotext from this GlossaryDocument
Is there any way to make docx file that contains autotext in yourself?

Answer (score 1):

A docx file *cannot* contain AutoText (Building Blocks). It is simply not supported. But why not save the document you're distributing as a template and the user can use it to create a new document whenever it's requiredf? That's what templates are for...

What *is* possible is to store the Word Open XML that represents the content to be re-used in (a) Custom XML Part(s). You'd need to code some kind of interface to enable the user to retrieve and insert this content. If the code should travel with the document, then as VBA - and it would then need to be a docm rather than docx file.

Given Word 2013 or newer, it's also possible to map/link a content control to a node in a Custom XML Part. But, again, this would require you to develop some kind of interface for the user.

Also possible would be a VSTO or Word JS API solution rather than VBA.